# cannot resolve symbol 'java.time.LocalDate' error in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, java-8, java-time

I am trying to use java.time.LocalDate in my android app, however if I try to import it, then any class from java.time gives a cannot resolve symbol error in Android studio 1.1

The only reason I could figure out for this is that it doesn't support java 8. Is that really the case?

Comment: That other Question is not really a duplicate. It asks about Java 8 in general, while this Question here focuses on a specific package of classes. And now in 2016, you can sort of use Java 8 language features in Android development but not use the java.time classes. So two different problems, two different solutions, and two different Questions.

Answer (score 19):

## Android API level 26

Android API level 26 gained an implementation of *java.time* including your [`LocalDate`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/time/LocalDate.html) class.

## Earlier Android

For Android <26, alternatives include:

- [ThreeTen-Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) is a back-port of much of the java.time functionality to Java 6 & 7.

  - [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) adapts ThreeTen-Backport to Android.
- [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) is commonly used in Android projects. Joda-Time inspired the java.time package in Java 8, but they are not drop-in replacements. The Joda-Time team advises migration to java.time.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Comment: +1 for the hint that Threeten-backport is not a complete backport (i18n-support is different due to changed environment and also less calendar support).

Comment: java.time was added in API26 https://developer.android.com/reference/java/time/LocalDate.html

Comment: @maracuja-juice So noted in my revised Answer. Thanks

Comment: I find it interesting that Android Studio does not warn of this?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, Android does not support Java-8. And about the new date/time-API contained in Java-8, you can look at this issue:

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=62192

Currently there are no plans to introduce JSR-310 (java.time-package) in Google Android.

Answer (score 2):

Finally date/time-API contained in Java 8 is added to Android API level 26 which was recently released.

[DateTimeFormatter API 26](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html)

Comment: but useless because it only support if your current min SDK is 26

Answer (score 1):

You can now use java.time APIs and other Java 8+ APIs without requiring a minimum API level for your app thank to API desugaring support (Android Gradle Plugin 4.0.0+)

https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support#library-desugaring

Briefly, you have to use Android Gradle plugin 4.0.0 or higher and include the `coreLibraryDesugaringEnabled true` in your compileOptions

```
android {
  defaultConfig {
    // Required when setting minSdkVersion to 20 or lower
    multiDexEnabled true
  }

  compileOptions {
    // Flag to enable support for the new language APIs
    coreLibraryDesugaringEnabled true
    // Sets Java compatibility to Java 8
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
  }
}
```