# Cannot resolve symbol 'LocalDateTime' in Java8, Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, java-8, java-time

I'm working with Android studio and use [Jack](https://developer.android.com/preview/j8-jack.html) to enable Java8 features, but it seems that LocalDateTime is still not implemented, is that the case?

[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28745205/cannot-resolve-symbol-java-time-localdate-error-in-android-studio) asks the same question, but it's dated since now Android supports Java8 with the Jack.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [cannot resolve symbol 'java.time.LocalDate' error in android studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28745205/cannot-resolve-symbol-java-time-localdate-error-in-android-studio)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know Jack, but it appears to not include an implementation of the java.time package built into Java 8 and later.

## java.time back-port

Fortunately, much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in the [ThreeTen-Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project, and further adapted to Android in the [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project.

See: [*How to use ThreeTenABP in Android project*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706)

Answer (score 1):

Try Using Joda-Time, it inspired the java.time package in Java 8

http://www.joda.org/joda-time/

And for your issue, check below

https://developer.android.com/preview/j8-jack.html#supported-features

Comment: Actually, the Joda-Time team advises migration to java.time. The ThreeTenABP project is an adaption of java.time for Android.