# How to check string date is in today?

Tags: java, android, if-statement

2019-12-07 20:13:04

i need if this date is in today my buton visibility is visible.

```
try {
        String dtStart = sales.getDate();
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss");
        Date date = format.parse(dtStart);


        Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
        Date today = now.getTime();
        if (date == today){
            holder.delete.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }else {
            holder.delete.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: String dtStart = sales.getDate();  ///   2019-12-07 20:13:04

Comment: Never use `==` to check the equality of objects

Comment: If you are using java8 or higher, you should not longer use the old date and calendar api

Comment: If both dates are Strings you must use date.equals(today)

Comment: You are using terrible date-time classes that were supplanted years ago by the *java.time* classes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the java-8 date time API, first your formatter is wrong month should represent with upper case letters `MM`, and use [DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) instead of legacy `SimpleDateFormat`

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

And then parse the input string into [LocalDateTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) using formatter

```
String date = "2019-12-07 20:13:04";

LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(date,formatter);
```

Finally compare the input date with current date using `equals`, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28745205/cannot-resolve-symbol-java-time-localdate-error-in-android-studio) is the information to get java-8 date time API on android

```
dateTime.toLocalDate().equals(LocalDate.now());  //true
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `DateUtils.isToday` method, to check if date is today:

```
try {
    String dtStart = sales.getDate();
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss");
    Date date = format.parse(dtStart);

    boolean isToday = DateUtils.isToday(date.getTime());
    if (isToday){
        holder.delete.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }else {
        holder.delete.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you already converted your date string to a date you can convert the `Date`-Object to a `Calendar`-Object and compare the year, month and day.

Example implementation:

```java
private boolean isToday(Date date) {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        Calendar toCompare = Calendar.getInstance();
        toCompare.setTimeInMillis(date.getTime());

        return calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR) == toCompare.get(Calendar.YEAR)
            && calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) == toCompare.get(Calendar.MONTH)
            && calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) == toCompare.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    }
```

Alternatively you can convert `Date` and `Calendar` to milliseconds and compare with the todays milliseconds.

Example implementation:

```java
private boolean isToday2(Date dateToCheck) {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

        // you have to set calendar object to 00:00:00
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR, 0);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

        // milliseconds of 1 day = 86400000
        return dateToCheck.getTime() - calendar.getTimeInMillis() < 86400000; 
    }
```

Both solutions **do not** handle however localized time correctly. So use with caution.

Answer (score 0):

We can use Java 8 Date-Time api as below :

```
    LocalDate dt2= LocalDate.of(2019,10,20);

    String dtStart= dt2.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE);

    LocalDate currentDt= LocalDate.now();

    if(currentDt.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE).equals(dtStart)) {
        // logic here 
    }else {
        //logic here
    }
```

Comment: Using `LocalDate`  is a good idea. Formatting before comparing is over-complicating things. Just comapre the two `LocalDate` objects as shown in [the answer by Deadpool](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59229116/5772882).