# How to convert String to LocalDate without using DateTimeFormatter

Tags: java, android, date, android-api-levels

i have a date in String "2020-06-02"

now i have to convert it in LocalDate but without using DateTimeFormatter.

is it possible.

```
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");
    LocalDate inputAdDate = LocalDate.parse(adDate, formatter);
```

as of now my code looks like this. but i dont want to use DateTimeFormatter as it is not supported in API level below 26.

Comment: Try `LocalDate.parse(adDate)`.

Comment: @Sweeper     java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Ljava/time/LocalDate;

Comment: See [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table), both `LocalDate` and `DateTimeFormatter` are supported. You probably haven't set things up correctly. Did you read [this](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support#library-desugaring)?

Comment: @Sweeper https://developer.android.com/reference/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter this link says its added in API level 26

Comment: And so does the [page for `LocalDate`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/time/LocalDate)...

Comment: Why can't you use `DateTimeFormatter`? Both classes are part of `java.time`.

Comment: The parse method with single parameter expects the input string should be in ISO-8601 format. And I see your input date string in the same format. So, you don’t need to pass the formatter paramter.

Comment: Well, are you sure that you *can* use `LocalDate`, but cannot use `DateTimeFormatter`? That seems weird to me, because both classes are added to the standard Java libraries at the same time.

Comment: Both `LocalDate` and `DateTimeFormatter` were introduced as part of java.time (the modern Java date and time API) in API level 26. Up to level 25 you may use both through the backport, the [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) (that’s ABP for Android backport).

Comment: Does this answer your question (if you read it well)? [cannot resolve symbol 'java.time.LocalDate' error in android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28745205/cannot-resolve-symbol-java-time-localdate-error-in-android-studio)

Answer (score 3):

Try this.

```
String date = "2020-06-02";
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse(date);
```

you need to import this package.

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
```

Answer (score 1):

Also, you can try the **java.text.SimpleDateFormat**

```
String strDate = "20-03-2019";
SimpleDateFormat sdfDateDMY = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
sdfDateDMY.parse(strDate);
```

Comment: I recommend against it (even though it will work under API level 26). The OP is seeking to use `LocalDate` from java.time the modern Java date and time API. (1) `SimpleDateFormat` will not work with `LocalDate`. (2) `SimpleDateFormat` is notoriously troublesome and long outdated.

Comment: I didn't know that `LocalDate` doesn't work with `SimpleDateFormat`. Good to know that. Thanks